# asp.net - LINQ Query with relational Data

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two tables Category and Document. See relationships in picture
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lTV8.png)

I wrote the following query to select data from both tables based on relationship

```
public List<DocumentViewModel> All()
        {
            var docs  = _context.Document.ToList();
            List<DocumentViewModel> docList = docs.Select(x => new DocumentViewModel
            { DocumentId = x.DocumentId,
              DocumentPath = x.DocumentPath,
              CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
              CategoryName = x.Category.CategoryName }).ToList();
            return docList;

        }
```

when this function is called , I get the following error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Here are my modals

## document

```
public class Document
    {
        [Key]
        public int DocumentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DocumentPath { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

## Category

```
public class Category
    {

        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    }
```

## DocumentViewModel

```
 public class DocumentViewModel
    {
        public int DocumentId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentPath { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Any Idea where am doing mistake?

Comment: That means your data integrity is flawed. Check in your data which documents are orphaned (has no corresponding category).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case there is no reason to get a List in memory and then do the projection, you can do this directly from EF instead. Even if there is no relationship defined EF will return `null` for `CategoryName` if you project the the results. If you go to memory first then an NRE is expected if there is no Category relationship.

```
public List<DocumentViewModel> All()
{
    return _context.Document.Select(x => new DocumentViewModel
        { DocumentId = x.DocumentId,
          DocumentPath = x.DocumentPath,
          CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
          CategoryName = x.Category.CategoryName}).ToList();
}
```

---

Original reason why it is failing.

1. There is at least one entity that does not have a corresponding relationship with Category.
2. You do not have lazy loading enabled (which is a good thing) and if that is the case you should use `Include` to return the relationship.